# how to sort an object in php?

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework, sorting, object

i have an property `$this->result` that holds an object:

```
array(40) {
  [0] => object(Model)#181 (7) {
    ["_id":protected] => string(2) "1"
    ["_img":protected] => string(95) "/1273720855.jpg"
  }
  [1] => object(Model)#224 (7) {
    ["_id":protected] => string(2) "2"
    ["_img":protected] => string(95) "/test.jpg"
  }
  [2] => object(Model)#182 (7) {
    ["_id":protected] => string(2) "3"
    ["_img":protected] => string(95) "/127377775.jpg"
  }
  [3] => object(Model)#224 (7) {
    ["_id":protected] => string(2) "4"
    ["_img":protected] => string(95) "/test.jpg"
  }
  [4] => object(Model)#182 (7) {
    ["_id":protected] => string(2) "5"
    ["_img":protected] => string(95) "/129586775.jpg"
  }
...
```

so if i do a loop i could get the `img` property:

```
foreach($this->result as $val){
    echo $val->getImg(); //'/1273720855.jpg'
}
```

What i would like to do is to sort the object so that the property's that has `/test.jpg` to be last or echo them last, like:

```
array(40) {
  [2] => object(Model)#182 (7) {
    ["_id":protected] => string(2) "3"
    ["_img":protected] => string(95) "/127377775.jpg"
  }
  [4] => object(Model)#182 (7) {
    ["_id":protected] => string(2) "5"
    ["_img":protected] => string(95) "/129586775.jpg"
  }
  [1] => object(Model)#224 (7) {
    ["_id":protected] => string(2) "2"
    ["_img":protected] => string(95) "/test.jpg"
  } 
  [3] => object(Model)#224 (7) {
    ["_id":protected] => string(2) "4"
    ["_img":protected] => string(95) "/test.jpg"
  }
....
```

i am interested in any solutions, even if i have to create a new array that i can sort afterwords, etc

ant ideas? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're after is usort.

http://php.net/usort

```
bool usort ( array &$array , callable $cmp_function )
```

You write the function to run the sort, and pass this function as parameter 2.
PHP will then loop over the array and run that function against each value in the array.

So you should have something resembling this:

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->getImg(), $b->getImg());
}

usort($this->result, "cmp");
```

Comment: how can i use it in a controller.  If i create a `public function cmp($a, $b)` then call it in a action with `usort($this->result, $this->cmp())`, i will get errors because i need to pass `$a` and `$b ` to the method

Comment: @Patrioticcow how did you get the object in the first place

Comment: in another method i used `fetchAll`, to query some results

Comment: That is good .. have you considered using SplHeapMax Instead ?

Comment: $a and $b are passed automatically by PHP. Basically it runs a bubblesort of the data in the array and compares 1 with 2, 1 with 3 (etc) until it finds the correct position.

Comment: @Patrioticcow If you want to pass a method, instead of a global function, then you need to look at example 3:
[link](http://au1.php.net/usort)

Note that the method needs to be static.

Answer (score 2):

I can see you have over `40 Images` and it can still grow  etc. .. and am not sure where you are getting it from but can just use Heap to store your images and it would be sorted automatically ...

```
$heap = new ImageStorage();


// Porpulate Storage form source 
$images = array(1 => "/1273720855.jpg",2 => "/test.jpg",3 => "/127377775.jpg",4 => "/test.jpg",5 => "/129586775.jpg");
foreach ( $images as $id => $img ) {
    $heap->insert(new Model($id, $img));
}

// Simple Output
echo "<pre>";
foreach ( $heap as $img ) {
    echo $img->getImg(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
/1273720855.jpg
/127377775.jpg
/129586775.jpg
/test.jpg
/test.jpg
```

Class Used

```
// Image Sotrage Class
class ImageStorage extends SplHeap {
    public function compare($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($b->getImg(), $a->getImg());
    }
}

// Emulation of your Model class
class Model {
    protected $_id;
    protected $_img;
    function __construct($id, $img) {
        $this->_id = $id;
        $this->_img = $img;
    }

    public function getID() {
        return $this->_id;
    }

    public function getImg() {
        return $this->_img;
    }
}
```